# Why newly created server from Amazon Linux AMI 1 showing missing patch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, patch

Can anyone help me to understand following problem?

I have created EC2 instance using amazon linux AMI 1. I did scan this instance using "AWS-AmazonLinuxDefaultPatchBaseline" and found one missing security patch for newely created server. I tried number of times with new server and it keep showing missing patch. [for Amazon Linux AMI 2 everything looks good].

common missing patch : `kernel.x86_64:0:4.14.181-108.257.amzn1`

Why It shows missing patches for newly created server?

Thank you in advance for your support

Comment: I checked my AL1, and for me it says that patch `kernel.x86_64:0:4.14.181-108.257.amzn1` is Compliant. What region are you at? I use us-east-1.

Comment: I wonder whether it needs a `sudo yum update`?

Comment: I am using us-east-1

Comment: Thanks John. I will check with sudo yum update in userdata script.

Comment: It seems amazon has updated the linux ami 1 on 18th June: https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2018.03-release-notes/. 
They have updated few packages on it. 
I was using AMI from old linux AMI 1 snapshot and hence I was seeing that missing patch.

I tried with latest AMI. It's working fine and it doesn't show any missing patch.